# Those vs They vs That

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number

In the following example conversation, what will be the best way to ask if the given resources help the person?

Example conversation:

> **John:** Hey Joe, I need to improve my chess, please help.
>   **Joe:** Hello John, please check these links: http://example1.com and http://example2.com.
>   Let me know if `[those, they, that]` help(s).

Thanks!

Comment: I would use _they_, referring to the **two links**. But you could also say _this_, meaning your **advice as a whole**. If you say _that_, you are referring to **his act of "checking"**.  So none is wrong; it's just a matter of your preferred emphasis.

Comment: Thank you @BrianHitchcock. Can I also use `these` to refer to the two links? e.g.: `Let me know if these helps.`

Comment: "These" implies that the things being referenced come *after* to me.

Answer (score 4):

Each is valid but has a slightly different meaning:

> Let me know if **those** help.

Let me know if [the things that I just mentioned] help. (Especially appropriate if this is not the first link or set of links that Joe has provided.)

> Let me know if **they** help.

Let me know if [the links] help. (Especially appropriate if this is the first communication about links. Joe isn't expecting there to be a need for any links other than the two in this sentence. And he isn't necessarily offering to gather more. He just wants a status update later to see if they were or weren't helpful.)

> Let me know if **that** helps.

Let me know if [my response] helps. //OR// Let me know if [your act of checking the links I provided] helps.

> Let me know if **these** help.

Let me know if [this set of links] helps. (Especially applicable if this is not the first set of links provided.) Obviously this is essentially the same meaning as "...if those help." The difference is extremely subtle: the word *these* implies somewhat more ownership over the links. If I talk about *those* links, I'm sending them out to be used or not. But if I talk about *these* links, I still have an interest in them for my own sake. This interpretation is not absolute, but it offers a rough idea of the subtlety that the reader may choose to confer.

Let me know if that...um...those...these...help.

Comment: I'm still unclear that there is any substantive difference between the first two options.